# In php is there a difference in overhead between a function and a method of class?

Tags: php, function, class, object, methods

I'm creating a website and part of the development allows administrators to 'freeze' someone's account (this prevents them logging in). I've created the functionality to 'freeze' / 'unfreeze' and check if an account is frozen or not within a class (along with all the other 'user' related methods).

However, it occurs to me that if the user is already logged in when the admin freezes the account I need to boot them out. So I need to check on every page refresh if their ID is 'frozen' or not.

I wondered if there is a bigger overhead in instantiating a new class and then calling my isUserFrozen() method every page refresh than just putting a normal function in to check if the user is frozen or not? (i.e. does instantiating an object have a bigger resource overhead?).

Thanks

Comment: Instantiating an object requires allocating memory, which is usually slower than calling a simple function, yes. However, that is certainly negligible and you are trying to optimize too early.

Comment: To state it a bit stronger: any difference in overhead here will be dwarfed by dozens of other factors, and this this is not something you should devote any energy to thinking about. In particular, I'm guessing the "freeze" flag is stored in some kind of database, so you have the overhead of reading it from there.

Comment: Why mark the question down? Knowing what you know, you can see that (in your words) this is 'micro-optimization'. However, I wasn't aware of that. Hence the genuine question. It was a clear, succinct and genuine question. Can you see how non-sensical it is to mark a question down because the OP doesn't know the answer. Therefore by your logic, every question on this board should start with one negative mark.... ? (@presiuslitelsnoflek thank you for the info, if you would like to 'answer' the question I'll mark it as the accepted answer. @imsop thank you for the clarification, much appreciated)

Comment: I voted it down because it's not constructive- you're not asking if the performance impact of function/method calls is worth the attention (you could time that yourself btw), but if there's a performance difference between calling a function and calling a method that does the same thing. Of course the answer would be yes, but that's irrelevant in practice, because the "overhead" of both is  measured in [microseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)

Comment: I was unaware that the difference was "irrelevant in practice, because that 'overhead' is measured microseconds". In fact, that answer (without the vote down) would have been most welcome.